# Creating thumbnails with the same name as the pictures

Tags: thumbnails

Please, here is my little code for creating thumbnails of pictures saved in a folder named 'pictures', and saving them in another folder named 'thumbs'.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.jpg
do
convert -thumbnail 100 $i thumbs/$i
done
```

However, there two things the program doesn't do:

1. It does not retain the name of the pictures in the thumbnail. For instance, I would want it to generate a thumbnail with the name `pic.jpg` for a picture named `pic.jpg`
2. Also, when I run the program, i don't want it to generate the thumbnail for a picture it has already generated its thumbnail, unless that picture has been modified.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [ImageMagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php),

> The ImageMagick command line consists of
>
> 1. one or more required input filenames.
> 2. zero, one, or more image settings.
> 3. zero, one, or more image operators.
> 4. zero, one, or more image sequence operators.
> 5. zero, one, or more image stacks.
> 6. zero or one output image filenames (required by convert, composite, montage, compare, import, conjure).

So you need to have the original image parameter before the `-thumbnail 100` command.

To only run convert if the file exists, you need to add an if test.

Also, in the for loop you have `for i in *.jpg` but then in the convert command you have `pictures/$i`. Unless I misunderstand what you're doing, these should both be the same, as I've done in my example script. If you want the thumbs directory inside the pictures directory, remove the `../` part from the convert command and if test. You will need to run this from the pictures directory, or if you don't want to, you can add `cd pictures` to the start of the script.

So, the script should be something like this:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

for i in *.jpg; do
    if [ "$i" -nt "../thumbs/$i" ]; then
        convert "$i" -thumbnail 100 "../thumbs/$i";
    fi
done;
```

Comment: This looks like it would work.

Comment: Thank very much mspencer. Your solution is working perfectly

Comment: @Duby Great! If this is the correct solution, please mark my answer as your accepted answer.